# No anonymous view of API Manager store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have stumbled into an issue with WSO2 API Manager inside a PoC environment. I have installed API Manager 1.7, BAM 2.4.1 and Identity Server 5.0.

Now I am not too sure whether I have misconfigured something, but when I now try to go to the store I am taken to the single sign on logon page rather than going into the store anonymously.

Has anyone else seen this behavior, and if so, what was the fix?

Comment: There is no switch as of now, to disable the anonymous view of the API store. So, it's unlikely this is a configuration change. This can be achieved only by customizing the store app. May be you have confused store with the API Publisher?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Nothing confused between the two. If I go to either store and publisher I am taken to the web SSO page. For Publisher, this would be expected behaviour but not for store.

Comment: If I alter APIMHOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/site.json so that enabled is set to false then when I go to the store then anonymous access works, but obviously websso does not.

Comment: Just dropped API Manger back to version 1.6 with the same RDBMS config as 1.7 and when you go to /store you are not prompted to sign in. It is looking very likely like a bug in 1.7.

Comment: Seems so. Please raise a bug in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER

Comment: Issue logged as requested, thanks.